# Python - Get notified when .xlsx file is sent to printer

Tags: python, excel, printing, operating-system

I use `os.startfile("path/to/some/file.xlsx","print")` to automatically print an excel workbook to the default printer. I then need to delete the file once it has printed, or at least, once it has been sent to the printer.

However, the `os.startfile()` function returns when the application launched by it finishes launching. In other words, it returns before the printing actually happens, because the application (MS Excel in this case) launches, and *then* it prints the file, and *then* it closes.

This means that a code like this won't work:

```
import os
os.startfile("path/to/file.xlsx","print")
os.remove("path/to/file.xlsx")
```

..because the file will get deleted before it gets sent to the printer by MS Excel.

And a code like this:

```
import os
import time
os.startfile("path/to/file.xlsx","print")
time.sleep(5)  # Delay to make sure the file has time to print
os.remove("path/to/file.xlsx")
```

..seems really bad practice to me, because some computers will need more time if they are really slower, and my application is time dependent *enough* to make something like `time.sleep(30)` unacceptable.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
import os
os.startfile("path/to/file.xlsx","print")
get_stuck_here_until_the_print_is_done()
os.remove("path/to/file.xlsx")
```

..or similar.

One way I thought of is by checking when the MS Excel process is over, which will mean that the whole printing process *has* to be over, but I can't do that in my case, because MS Excel could already be running on the PC for some other reason, which I have to deal with.

Windows 7, by the way.

MS Excel 2013, by the way.